# Floating LI's in IE 6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm building a navigation using the simple `<ul><li></li><ul>` system and floating them to the left side so they appear inline. The follow code works in **all** browsers except IE 6.

The HTML

```
<div id="sandbox_container">
    <div id="sandbox_modalbox">
        <div>
            <ul id="sandbox_modalbox_nav">
                <li id="Intro" class="modal_active"><a href="#Intro">Item 1</a></li>
                <li id="Queries"><a href="#Queries">Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- more content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#sandbox_container { 
    min-height: 385px; 
    width: 940px; 
    padding-bottom: 20px 
}
#sandbox_modalbox { 
    width: 940px; 
    padding-top: 5px; 
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

ul#sandbox_modalbox_nav { 
    width: 936px; 
    height: 52px; 
    margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
    padding-top: 0px; 
    display: block; 
}
ul#sandbox_modalbox_nav li {
    height:52px; 
    float: left; 
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px; 
    display: block; 
}
ul#sandbox_modalbox_nav li a { 
    padding: 12px 30px 0px 30px; 
    height: 52px; 
    display: block; 
}
```

I also put it up on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/izeka/edit).

I understand the problem is that I must define a width for the `<li>` for IE to float it properly, however I would prefer these remain variable width. Is there anyway to float them properly **without** restricting the width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am understanding the problem correctly then in browsers other than IE6 the list items appear next to each other, but in IE6 they appear on top of each other.

If this is the case, it may be because the a elements are not floated even though their containing elements are. I would just use a conditional comment and add the following for IE6 only:

```
ul#sandbox_modalbox_nav li a { float:left; }
```

Also, [Neall is right on track with the whitespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114442/floating-lis-in-ie-6/1114460#1114460), even if it doesn't fix your current display problem it may cause some unwanted space to appear between items later.

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem? The OP says he "wants to do X" but never says how IE6 is misbehaving. If he wants them to appear inline he should either a) make them inline elements, or b) float them.

Comment: You were correct with the assumption, and your solution works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can think of, I can't imagine how to declare a width that can change, except by defining it in `em`s. If you have a content that you know is likely to be less than ten characters, then `width: 11em; padding: 0.5em 1em;` is likely to offer enough space for the content while still defining a width.

Comment: Perhaps worded poorly, I was more interested if I could get around this using another method without declaring a width, although this is the answer I expected anyways. Thanks

Comment: @Ian, No; I got what you wanted, I just couldn't think of a get-round for your problem, besides setting at least a fluid-width. 

You could, perhaps, use a script (server- or client-side) to set the width to one em greater than the longest string length found in the menu `ul`. But again, it's not what you really want.

Comment: @Ian, as an addenda, does `width: auto;` help?

Comment: Also bear in mind that `width` means `min-width` to IE6. Some of your elements may be expanding without your knowledge. In there other browsers, do the items appear to be crammed in tightly?

Comment: Everything appears as I desire in browsers other than IE, the issue was IE items were simply stacking not floating, Zack's post solved the issue without adding a width.

Answer (score 0):

IE 6 has some bugs with whitespace between `<li>` elements. Try putting all your list items on the same line with no space between them.

Edit: On further inspection, I don't think the whitespace is your problem. Your example has a lot of extraneous styles - it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: No success ):                           ``

Comment: There's a lot of stuff missing, I just stripped out everything that wasn't needed visually and didn't directly affect the size of elements.

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this by setting the floated list items to width: 0 for IE6. This for one reason or other causes them to have the correct dynamic width.

You can either do this in a conditional comment:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">ul#sandbox_modalbox_nav li { width: 0; }</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Or simply take advantage of IE's lack of support for CSS selectors, by setting the width to 0, and then back to the default "auto" for modern browsers:

```
ul#sandbox_modalbox_nav li { width: 0; }
ul#sandbox_modalbox_nav > li { width: auto; }
```